# Convert a Linked List of type Integer to Set of type String in JAVA

Tags: java, list, linked-list, hashset

I have a `List` of `Integers` but I would like to take that `List` and convert it to a `HashSet`.

For example my list is as follows:

```
1234
5678
1234
7627
4328
```

But I would like to take that `list` and convert the string of integers to a `HashSet` so it doesn't include repeats. What is the best way to accomplish this?

My `list` is defined as

```
static List<Integer> list;
```

And my `HashSet` is defined as

```
static HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);
```

My error is that I can't convert from int to string so what can I do to solve this?

Comment: If all you want to do is eliminate duplicates, what's wrong with `HashSet<Integer>`?  Do you really need them stored as strings?

Comment: It is a string of integers

Comment: "A string of integers"?  I thought you had a `List` of integers.  What is this "string of integers" you're talking about?  And what does a "string of integers" have to do with whether to convert each _single_ integer to a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using an ArrayList as the instantiated form of List<>:

```
    for (Integer value : list) {
        set.add(value.toString());
    }
```

This will iterate through your List and take each integer, convert it to a String, and add that value to your HashSet.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, if this was the answer you used feel free to mark it answered.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use streams:

```
Set<String> set = list.stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

First, you stream the list. Then, each element is converted to string and finally all elements are collected to a set. By default, [`Collectors.toSet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--) creates a `HashSet`, though this is not guaranteed by the specification.

If you want a guaranteed `HashSet`, you could use `Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new)`:

```
Set<String> set = list.stream()
    .map(Object::toString)
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

using Java 8 streams:

```
set = list.stream().map(e -> e.toString()).collect(Collectors.toCollection(HashSet::new));
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/fork/KovAhx)

or without using streams

```
for(Integer i : list) set.add(Integer.toString(i));
```